# Sending mail with gmail SMTP (Fixing someone's code)

Tags: php, function, email, smtp, fsockopen

This may be long, so I'm sorry.

Recently I decided I was going to try and fix a code used by a computer lab to send e-mails. It used to work until they recently tried to change the sending e-mail address. My problem? I know little about this type of coding and what pieces of code they changed. I found the function that they use to send the mail. I was hoping someone could help point me out to what would be the problem. Or what I can change to make it work. I'm thinking it's because a password is never asked for. But I don't understand what the person who wrote this code was doing exactly.

Here's the code I'm looking at.

```
function SendMail($ToName, $ToEmail, $FromName, $FromEmail, $Subject, $Body, $Header)
{
$SMTP = fsockopen("smtp.gmail.com", 465);

$InputBuffer = fgets($SMTP, 1024);

fputs($SMTP, "HELO $smtp.gmail.com\n");
$InputBuffer = fgets($SMTP, 1024);
fputs($SMTP, "MAIL From: $FromEmail\n");
$InputBuffer = fgets($SMTP, 1024);
fputs($SMTP, "RCPT To: $ToEmail\n");
$InputBuffer = fgets($SMTP, 1024);
fputs($SMTP, "DATA\n");
$InputBuffer = fgets($SMTP, 1024);
fputs($SMTP, "$Header");
fputs($SMTP, "From: $FromName <$FromEmail>\n");
fputs($SMTP, "To: $ToName <$ToEmail>\n");
fputs($SMTP, "Subject: $Subject\n\n");
fputs($SMTP, "$Body\r\n.\r\n");
fputs($SMTP, "QUIT\n");
$InputBuffer = fgets($SMTP, 1024);

fclose($SMTP);
}
```

They press a button and it sends the email. Or runs the function at least.
I found that when they press the button certain variables are called. The other variables are called from a database that stores personal info. (changed the email to a random one to post this question.)

```
$fname = mysql_result($results, 0, "fname");
$FromName = "Support Center";
$FromEmail = "JonStevens93@hotmail.com";
$Subject = "Computer Finished";
$Body = "Your computer is fixed.";
$Header = "Computer";
```

Would anyone be able to possibly point me in the right direction. Or can someone please explain how to make the program output an error message? I've googled around and found topics talking about it but I'm still lost. Would it be better to just write a new code and not even try to fix it since I'm a novice? Any help is really appreciated as I'm a slight novice at this type of code. I can read it and understand it, but... I don't understand the in depth functions.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just rewrite SendMail function contents and use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class instead of manual socket interaction. It can send emails in different ways - mail() function, sendmail or SMTP. It is easy to configure and it will throw exceptions when something is wrong during SMTP sessions. Just place it somewhere in your site and look at examples provided with the package.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thank you for trying to help me, this is exactly what I've been looking for. But I'm still lost a bit I'm afraid.

If I change the function to...

function SendMail ()
{
*all the default phpMailer info in here*
}

and if I fill out the default phpMailer info it should send an email anytime I call on the function SendMail correct? 

I know I need to call certain variables from differen .php pages. The two variables I need are $ToName and $ToEmail. The email and name depends on which work order is open. So the only thing that can't be fixed are the To Email and name.